# Are copy written .GIF videos ok to use as a visual aid?

Tags: discussion, scope, policy

Copy written text material get sited all the time. Is it ok to use video clips and site them?

[Where or where not to be when an asteriod is coming?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13453/where-or-where-not-to-be-when-an-asteriod-is-coming)

[image]

Comment: Is there a difference between using pictures or videos, which are under (restrictive) copywrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that they are OK as long as they truly add something to explain what the question is about.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue for me here is not even the copyright (though it is of course an issue) but more the fact that those gifs do not bring anything to the question asked, and are in fact rather distracting (for instance i'm currently writing this answer with my browser window reduced enough NOT to see that gif consistently while typing this).